# How to reuse a node for multiple google maps in ionic

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I want a page that allows users to get their current locations in a map and also enter custom locations in a text field and have it displayed in a map as well. At first, I tried using one DOM node for both purposes but I get the error that that node already has a mapID.

According to https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/, I'm setting the first argument of `GoogleMaps.create()` to the ViewChild decorator of a certain dom node:

```
<p (click)='getLocation()'>get my location</p> 

<input (input)='searchLocation($event.target.value)' type=text placeholder='please help' />

<div id=forCss #displayMap [innerHTML]='resetMap'></div>
```

In typescript, I have

```
@ViewChild('displayMap')targetDiv:any;

  getLocation() {

   const locationOptions = {enableHighAccuracy:true,timeout:105000},

    // this should only run once since our location is static
    // TODO: save the location in a member prop
    map = GoogleMaps.create(this.targetDiv.nativeElement, {

      camera: {
        target: { lat: 0, lng: 0 } // init map instance
      }
    });

    map.getMyLocation(locationOptions)

    .then(myLocation => this.loadMap(myLocation))

    .catch(e => console.log(e))
  }

searchLocation (place:string) {

    Geocoder.geocode({address: place})
    .then(GeocoderResults => {

      console.log(GeocoderResults); // works seamlessly

      this.loadMap(GeocoderResults[0].position)
    })
  }


  loadMap(locObj){

   var el = this.targetDiv.nativeElement; // should point to displayMap

    el.removeAttribute ('__pluginMapId') // trying to free the node manually. works partially


    let myLoc = { lat: locObj.latLng.lat, lng: locObj.latLng.lng },

    mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
      camera: { target: myLoc, zoom: 18, tilt: 30 }
    },

    newMap = GoogleMaps.create(el, mapOptions);

console.log(newMap, newMap.getDiv()); // map object returned but no node to attach to

    // Wait the MAP_READY before using any methods.
    newMap.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY)
      .then(() => {

        newMap.addMarker({ title: 'Ionic', icon: 'blue', animation: 'DROP', position: myLoc })
          .then(marker => {
            marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK)
              .subscribe(() => { alert('clicked'); });
          });

      });
  }
```

This doesn't display the map so I tried wrapping the target node in a container and altering it whenever a new map is required. The problem with that approach is that contrary to what the docs say, the @ViewChild doesn't update whenever a change to the selector is made i.e

```
<div id=forCss [innerHTML]='resetMap'><div #displayMap>old node</div> </div>
```

And trying to kick out the garbage selectors they wrap my elements with like this in typescript

```
this.resetMap = `<div #displayMap>replaced thing here</div>`; // console.warning moans about xss content replacement yada yada

console.log(el, this.targetDiv.nativeElement); // targetDiv still displays the 'old node' :'(

newMap = GoogleMaps.create(this.targetDiv.nativeElement, mapOptions);
```

The above doesn't trigger view child change so the same detached (and used) node is passed to the above call.

So how do I correctly select a valid node to pass to the GoogleMap constructor and reuse or replace it subsequently wherever that is required?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to reinstall the `multiple_maps` branch version.

```
$> cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-googlemaps

$> cordova plugin add https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps.git#multiple_maps --variable ...
```

If the above does not work, you need to manage the map instance by your code.
The map is not a HTML element, you need to `detach/attach` action when you want to display the map.

This is idea, for example:

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('HomePage: ionViewDidLoad');
    this.loadMap();
  }
  loadMap() {
    // Executes here only the first time
    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas');
  }
  ionViewWillLeave() {
    // Before leaving, detaches the map view from browser.
    this.map.setDiv(null);
  }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    if (this.map) {
      // Attaches the map view to browser, second time
      this.map.setDiv('map_canvas');
    }
  }
```

Comment: OK thanks a lot. I'll give it a try as soon as I recharge my machine

Comment: Hello there. I tried your second solution but it doesn't work any more that displaying the words GOOGLE  at the bottom of the target element. My code is at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/nmeri17/b808f39c594cfd6fcc9b52330b15f8cd). It currently doesn't complain about loaded maps anymore, the situation I'm suffering from is that nothing calls at this point `this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY)
      .subscribe(() => {`. It's dead from that point down

Comment: He says his map is black and displays the first time. MINE HAS NEVER DISPLAYED EVER!. I don't understand what you intended to point or with the link. My "map" looks like this every time I open the page https://postimg.org/image/4gb1oeu2j/. Have you not run the code in my previous comment or spotted what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Does this plugin make any background request to Google map api? No network request is made in my developer console. Also a code example I saw online by someone using the Geolocation plugin includes 
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEYcallback=initMap" async defer></script> in their index.html but the installation instructions of your api doesn't mention this. I've added it however but it still doesn't work.

Comment: >MINE HAS NEVER DISPLAYED EVER
Okay, please make an issue at https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues

And please share your repository on Github or other git repository services. If private repository, please invite me.

Comment: > Does this plugin make any background request to Google map api
Nop. But the native APIs works without network.

`<script src="maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/…; async defer></script>` is the Google Maps JavaScript API, not this plugin.